# How to make a clickable imageview from png image

Tags: android, imageview

In my App clickable imageview  (Android Studio) and I used a PNG image with transparent background, but when I run the app it looks like when I click near the image it's getting clicked, can you help me out !

Here's a screenshot :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhN1y.jpg

My XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/dim_foreground_material_light">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="16"
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Java Code

```
package com.example.bibiwars.skills;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



 }
```

I don't know why the app always crashes ? how cam i solve this issue?

:::This is the logcat:::

`06-24 13:28:09.815    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-24 13:28:10.998    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
06-24 13:28:10.999    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c85570, tid 1922
06-24 13:28:11.042    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-24 13:28:14.228    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c856b0, tid 1953
06-24 13:28:14.243    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-24 13:28:14.567    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-24 13:28:14.728    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 13:28:14.728    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c7ac00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 13:28:14.887    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 13:28:20.268    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 322 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 13:28:36.548    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 13:28:36.644    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 13:28:36.644    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c7ac00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 13:28:37.712    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 13:28:41.599    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 13:28:41.599    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c7ac00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 13:28:52.650    1922-1922/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 644 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 13:29:15.022    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 13:29:15.022    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cd3b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 13:29:20.624    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 13:29:20.624    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cd3b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 13:29:31.927    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 13:29:31.927    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cd3b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 13:35:56.876    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 13:35:56.876    1922-1953/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cd3b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 14:20:41.195    2422-2422/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 191 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 14:20:53.827    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 14:20:53.827    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa685b980, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 14:20:54.379    2422-2422/com.example.bibiwars.skills I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-24 14:21:08.637    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 14:21:08.637    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa68c73c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 14:21:12.162    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 14:21:12.162    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa68c73c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-24 14:21:16.752    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 14:21:16.752    2422-2437/com.example.bibiwars.skills W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa68c73c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS`

Comment: Post the logcat, please.

Comment: Similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343266/how-to-prevent-onclick-method-on-transparent-portion-of-a-png-loaded-imageview

Comment: Where are you using a Dialog Interface? Could you try deleting your import android.content.DialogInterface?

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: here i posted my logcat, also i tried deleting android.content.DialogInterface and nothing was changed

Comment: From your logcat we can see that you are using OpenGL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the area of the square enclosing the cirle, it is bound to happen, to prevent that you will have to specify that you don't want touch over there.

For that do this,

1. Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the image.
2. Calculate the width and height of the image.
3. In onClick, get X' and Y' coordinates of the touch. Calculate

   ```
   touch = (X'- X)^2 + (Y'- Y)^2 - (Width/2)^2

   if(touch<=0)
       //It's a Click!!
   else
       //It's in the transparent area.
   ```

But, this will only work for circles. Even if you create a transparent image doesn't the transparent area doesn't receive touch events. Every image is a rectangle.

Comment: What happened, I had solved it! You accepted the answer.

Comment: yeah but after that I couldn't do it alone... I'm still a beginner so can you please show me how to get those X, Y, X', Y', width, height ? then I can surely accept!

Comment: being a beginner doesn't excuse you to copy codes, use onMeasure. and do some research